# Root Locus Diagrams - "Breakaway Point"

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Say that we have a root locus diagram with n poles and m zeroes. And we determine that the root locus on the real axis lies between two of these poles and breaks away from the real axis and tends to infinity somewhere in between these points.

There are formulae to determine what angle the asymptote makes with the real axis as well as what point the root locus "breaks away" from the real axis.

I have noticed from some examples that the point at which the root locus breaks is often half-way in between the two poles I was talking about. But sometimes its not. Is there a rule of thumb to determine when this is the case? This would make drawing root locus diagrams much quicker and give me more intuition on the topic.

This might sound a bit confusing, http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/econtrolhtml/RootLocus/RLocus1ARCADE.html has some examples on root locus diagrams. The "Three Real Poles" and "Three Poles, One Zero" examples show what I meant about the "breakaway point" being exactly halfway between two poles whilst my textbook uses long formulae to determine a "breaksway point" which is not halfway between the two poles.

Comment: The link says the centroid is _not_ located at midpoint in both cases. Did I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: @HebeleHododo I mean the point at which the loci depart from the real axis. In that example, they depart at -2, halfway between the two real poles -1 and -3

Comment: I am looking at the link you gave. Neither "Three Poles" nor "Three Poles, One Zero" examples depart at -2. It says next to root locus of Three Poles: "Unlike a system with two poles, the centroid is **not** located at the midpoint between the poles at -1 and -3." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @HebeleHododo maybe my terminology is not correct, but the Three Poles, One Zero example, There are poles at -1, -3 and -5 with a zero at -4. The loci from -1 and -3 move towards each other and then depart the real axis at -2, although the vertical asymptote the eventually approach is not -2 (about -2.5), I am interested in the point at which they leave the real axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively you can think that open loop poles tend to "push" and zeros tend to "pull" the root loci. Suppose you have only two real poles, then roots break away at exactly the halfway between them as in System 2 in your link. If you add another real pole as in System 3, it pushes the roots, hence the break away point.

Suppose you have real poles at -1, -3 and a zero at -5. Then zero tends to pull the roots and in fact a circle with center at -5 and radius a little less than 3 will occur. Hence, the break away point will be between -1 and -3, but closer to -3 due to the effect of the zero. Of course there will be another break away point close to -8.

In System 4, zero at -4 is closer to other poles than the pole at -5, hence it pulls the roots "more strong" then the pole pushes. But their effects will even out at infinity, hence asymptote has a 90 degree angle. Note that angle of the asymptotes are directly determined by the difference between number of roots and zeros.